# Use integer representation instead of floats when writing a numpy array to a text file

Tags: python, csv, numpy

Currently I have the code:

```
numpy.savetxt("FILENAME.csv", Z, delimiter=",")
```

This produces `FILENAME.csv` that contains:

```
1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
```

However, I want it to be:

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

How do I modify my code to make these changes?

Note that `Z` is an `np array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is the default format, `fmt='%.18e'`.

You may specify the keyword argument `fmt` to provide a format for integers:

```
numpy.savetxt("FILENAME.csv", Z, fmt='%d', delimiter=",")
```

To provide the values on one line, just reshape `Z`:

```
numpy.savetxt("FILENAME.csv", Z.reshape(1,-1), fmt='%d', delimiter=", ")
```